# Tomcat HttpServletResponse writing to getOutputStream() always causes OutOfMemory error for large file downloads

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

@Duplicate - this is not a duplicate - the similar question specifically asks about Liferay SendFile method which does not work for larges files. The below question is in regards to simply writing a large file to a Tomcat outpustream. The other question is not answered anyways, rather, they tell him to file an issue with Liferay which is not an answer to any question. The below code is the code for the Liferay SendFile() method. Directing somebody to Liferay support is not a solution.

I am constantly getting an OutOfMemory: Java heap space error when I try and write large files to the HttpServletResponse getOutputStream() - despite attempts at using a buffer, Apache Commons IOUtils.ChunkedOutputStream, writing the output in chunks - nothing works. Same error happened when I use the HttpServletResponse getWriter() method and try it that way also.. But here is my code for the getOutputStream() -

I am writing a download-file feature for my Portlet, and I need it to be able to handle very large files - but it's struggling right now with even 1.4gb files.

```
final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);

  // Regular Output Stream
  BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(httpResponse.getOutputStream());

  // Also tried using this from Apache Commons, still did not work
  //ChunkedOutputStream outputStream = new ChunkedOutputStream(outputStream);

  // Desired File Download
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(source_file);

while (remainingLength > 0) {
  int readBytes = is.read(bytes, 0, (int)Math.min(remainingLength, bufferSize));
  if (readBytes == -1) {
    break;
  }

  // Write it
  outputStream.write(bytes, 0, readBytes);

  // Other Attempts - none of these worked
  //IOUtils.writeChunked(bytes, outputStream); //This does not work
  //IOUtils.write(bytes, outputStream); // Neither does this

  remainingLength -= readBytes;

  // Attempted to flush after every 1mb written - but it does not fix the issue
  if(buffer >= bufferSize) {
    outputStream.flush();
    buffer = 0;
  } else {
    buffer += readBytes;
  }
}

// ALTERNATIVELY - We also tried using Apache IOUtils.copy() and copyLarge()
IOUtils.copyLarge(is, outputStream);
//IOUtils.copy(is, outputStream);

// This is in a finally {} block, try{} encloses the above code 
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is, outputStream);
```

The outofmemory exception happens on the outputStream.write() line - and I cannot figure out how to correctly write a file to the output stream that does not cause that exception to get thrown. It works fine for smaller 200mb files, but never for larger ones.

My startup arguments for Tomcat are -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms2048m

Also note: I added a log at the end of the loop to write the total written bytes, and converted it to MB. It gets to 512mb.

The Updated Stack Trace - I restarted the server and got a better one.

The error happens on the outputStream.write() - and if you dig into the stack trace the actual line that throws the error is in UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.java:91 on the line

```
byte[] newBuffer = new byte[newBufferSize];
```

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet filemanager Servlet threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.write(UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.ServletOutputStreamAdapter.write(ServletOutputStreamAdapter.java:54)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at com.healthmap.FileManager.download(FileManager.java:370)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:163)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:249)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:90)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:212)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:628)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:308)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doProcessAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:75)

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the `OOME`. Also, what is the declaration / allocation for `bytes`?

Comment: @ChristopherShultz 1024 is bytes allocation

Comment: Your stack trace does not look complete -- at the end, it says "Caused by: OutOfMemoryErrr: Java heap space" but then there is no additional stack trace. Also, any idea what line is `LiferayPortlet.java:181`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I restarted the server and got a better stack trace.. The line in my script that causes the error is outputStream.write() and if you dig into it, the error is caused in `UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.java:91` because of `byte[] newBuffer = new byte[newBufferSize];`

Comment: Maybe you are really running out of memory. What is `newBufferSize`?

Comment: I am stepping into it now and I will find out - because I can't modify it and print anything to console form that file, as I can only see the src in a .class file. My file I am doing everything is FileManager.java, and everything below that are compiled .class files @ChristopherSchultz.

Just wanted to add though - when I try and write large files to the output stream, it will write succesfully up until 512mb, then it throws that error. My server is configured at startup with the -x** flags I mentioned above, and when I check it's total memory, it has 2048mb available, and only 400mb used

Comment: Is there possibly a limit set to the HttpServletResponse getOutputStream() at 512mb? Because it stops writing and throws the OOM: heap space error after writing 512mb exactly, every single time.

Comment: @ChristopherShultz !!! I stepped into the code, and set a conditional breakpoint to watch what happens around when it writes 512mb and throws the OOME - and I saw what happened!! You were right -

The `newBufferSize` value of the `new Byte[newBufferSize]` statement that caused the OOME was steadily changing to different values like 2088 bytes, 4176, 8352 etc.... All were smaller numbers - but when it crashed, the value spiked randomly and massively, up to 1073741824 bytes (1073mb) - any idea why this could be happening? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Looks like a bug in Liferay to me.